# Unable to get the property value when using styles

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a custom control that I apply the template to. Inside custom control I have defined properties that are binded to the templated control inside the style. If I'm subscribed to the Loaded event and trying to get the properties they are null. If however I'm ovveriding the OnPropertyChanged they have values. Can someone please explain why is that so.
Please look at the ColumnEntity property.

Thank you.

I've removed some parts for briefety

```
 <!-- This code is based on http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/DataGridFilterLibrary.aspx -->

  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridColumnFilter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DataGridColumnFilter}">
                <Border Background ="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Background="AliceBlue"
                        Text="{Binding 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DataGridColumnFilter}}, 
                            Path=QueryEntity.Text, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}">
                    </TextBox>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey 
    TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:DataGridColumnFilter}, ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}" 
    TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <local:DataGridColumnFilter Grid.Row="0"
                        DataGridEntity="{Binding 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=.}" 
                        ColumnEntity="{Binding 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}, Path=Column}"
                        ItemsSourceEntity ="{Binding 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, 
                            Path=ItemsSource}"/>

                    <theme:DataGridHeaderBorder Grid.Row="1" 
                            SortDirection  ="{TemplateBinding SortDirection}"
                            IsHovered      ="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                            IsPressed      ="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                            IsClickable    ="{TemplateBinding CanUserSort}"
                            Background     ="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush    ="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding        ="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            SeparatorBrush ="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}"
                            SeparatorVisibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}">

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                            Text               ="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            VerticalAlignment  ="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </theme:DataGridHeaderBorder>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```
public class DataGridColumnFilter : Control
{
    static DataGridColumnFilter()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(DataGridColumnFilter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DataGridColumnFilter)));
    }

    public DataGridColumnFilter()
    {
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DataGridColumnFilter_Loaded);
    }

    void DataGridColumnFilter_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // here is would be null!
        var controller = ColumnEntity;
    }
    // For some reason this seems to be the only place to access the ColumnEntity
           protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Property == ItemsSourceEntityProperty && e.OldValue != e.NewValue && null != DataGridEntity && ColumnEntity is DataGridColumn)
        {
             // here it works fine. The property has a proper value
              var controller = ColumnEntity;
        }

        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
    }

    #region Properties

    public Query QueryEntity
    {
        get { return (Query)GetValue(QueryEntityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(QueryEntityProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty QueryEntityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("QueryEntity", typeof(Query), typeof(DataGridColumnFilter));

    public DataGridColumn ColumnEntity
    {
        get { return (DataGridColumn)GetValue(ColumnEntityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColumnEntityProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnEntityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnEntity", typeof(DataGridColumn), typeof(DataGridColumnFilter));

    public DataGrid DataGridEntity
    {
        get { return (DataGrid)GetValue(DataGridEntityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataGridEntityProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridEntityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataGridEntity", typeof(DataGrid), typeof(DataGridColumnFilter));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSourceEntity
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceEntityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceEntityProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceEntityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSourceEntity", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DataGridColumnFilter));

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the OnApplyTemplate event instead of loaded event

`public override void OnApplyTemplate()`

Answer (score 0):

Binding evaluation happens later in the loading process after the whole Visual Tree has been constructed. Rather than relying on a single event to collect values just use PropertyChanged handlers on the DependencyProperties, which you've already confirmed are giving you the expected values.

You can also simplify the ColumnEntity to use `ColumnEntity="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Column}"`